# Set height and width of two div element hardcore and display: inline-block also given same margin

Tags: html, css

I have set height and width of two div element hardcore having class `dices` and also set display to inline-block and given same margin. I have put 6 div inside in one of them, having class `dots` which having fixed height and width, but that div moved slightly downwards why it is happening as it should remain in its position. And I also remove default margin.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> -->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dicegame.css">
    <style>
        * {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        body {

            background-color: rgb(104, 103, 102);
        }

        h1 {
            color: rgb(14, 197, 197);
            font-size: 6rem;
            font-style: italic;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 25px;
        }

        .player {
            margin-top: 25px;
            color: rgb(14, 197, 197);

            text-align: center;
        }

        .player h4 {
            padding: 0px 52px;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 2rem;
        }

        .dice {

            text-align: center;
        }

        .dices {
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 20px 10px;
            background-color: rgb(165, 13, 13);

        }

        .dots {
            width: 90px;
            height: 60.66px;
            background-color: white;
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius: 10px;
            margin: 2px;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>
        Referesh Me
    </h1>
    <div class="player">
        <h4>Player 1</h4>
        <h4>Player 2</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="dice">
        <div class="dices">
            <div class="dots"></div>
            <div class="dots"></div>
            <div class="dots"></div>
            <div class="dots"></div>
            <div class="dots"></div>
            <div class="dots"></div>

        </div>

        <div class="dices">


        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to lie with the way inline-block is interpreted.

Making the parent element dice use a flex wrap aligns the two dices elements vertically:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> -->
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dicegame.css">
  <style>
    * {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: rgb(104, 103, 102);
    }
    
    h1 {
      color: rgb(14, 197, 197);
      font-size: 6rem;
      font-style: italic;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 25px;
    }
    
    .player {
      margin-top: 25px;
      color: rgb(14, 197, 197);
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .player h4 {
      padding: 0px 52px;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 2rem;
    }
    
    .dice {
      text-align: center;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: wrap;
     justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .dices {
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      border: 2px solid black;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 20px 10px;
      background-color: rgb(165, 13, 13);
    }
    
    .dots {
      width: 90px;
      height: 60.66px;
      background-color: white;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 10px;
      margin: 2px;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>
    Referesh Me
  </h1>
  <div class="player">
    <h4>Player 1</h4>
    <h4>Player 2</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="dice">
    <div class="dices">
      <div class="dots"></div>
      <div class="dots"></div>
      <div class="dots"></div>
      <div class="dots"></div>
      <div class="dots"></div>
      <div class="dots"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="dices">


    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you sir but why this is not happening in the case of inline-block